# Flutter firebase change a field after 1 year

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am building a feature where user subscribe to app by making payment, it sets a value in cloud Firestore like {"subscribed": true}. I want to set the value false after one year. Can you anyone show me an example how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can directly use `Firestore` to schedule any task in the future. If you're not running any custom backend service, then you probably have to look into doing it with `Cloud Tasks` (`Cloud Functions` to trigger them).

You can create a cloud function to schedule the `Task` and one function to handle the task (this will include the logic to update the `subscribed` flag to `false` again.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it ?

Comment: Well, you'll need to write Node JS code for Cloud Function and enable App Engine and Cloud Task from Google Cloud Console. You'll find some great resources online for using Cloud Tasks and Firestore in Cloud Functions, they're just SDKs as Cloud Functions work on with Node JS (includes other options as well).

Comment: I can do it with cron jobs on node.js, I don't have any backend service running for this app.

Comment: I got it that you don't have a custom backend. That's why I am serving you with a solution using Cloud Functions. If you were having a custom backend, obviously I won't suggest using Cloud Tasks or other services.